# I am stuck at some sql server queries

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I have these tables in my database:

```
USER_ACCOUNT
USER_CHARACTER
```

> USER_ACCOUNT Columns: AccountID, Character1,Character2,Character3
>
> USER_CHARACTER Columns: It holds all data for specific character
>   separately but in this specific case we'll need columns UserID and
>   SpecialPoints.

So, how to grab all `character1,character2 and character3 from USER_ACCOUNT` by providing an `AccountID` and check which one of them have `>50000 SpecialPoints from USER_CHARACTER`?

If it finds that one of these characters has `>50000 SpecialPoints`, to update the specific character and remove `-50000 SpecialPoints`.

I will create two checks on my php script but I am stuck on creating the actual queries.

I am using **MSSQL Server 2005**

Comment: What SQL dialect are you using? MySQL? MSSQL? PostgreSQL?

Comment: your question is not clear. please add an example with some data to clearly express what you mean

Comment: We've got `$_SESSION['AccountID']`, so I need to check in `USER_ACCOUNT` for these characters associated with the account id which the session will provide. After that I must check if these total of 3 characters has any SpecialPoints .....

Comment: again, it's not clear. Really you will save yourself and the helpers on SE alot of time and effort if you just included in your question, one trivial example with data. It will make it more easier for us to help you. Sometime expressing a problem in English is difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I'll take a stab at it in hopes that I understand the questions, but more likely it will provide a basis to help clarify.

Note: I am assuming that USER_ACCOUNT.Character1 is, for example, a FK to something in USER_CHARACTER. It should be.

A couple ways to get you started.

First some sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE USER_ACCOUNT (AccountID INT, Character1 INT,Character2 INT,Character3 INT)
CREATE TABLE USER_CHARACTER (CharacterID INT, SpecialPoints INT)
GO

INSERT INTO USER_ACCOUNT VALUES (1,10,20,30),(2,40,50,60)
INSERT INTO USER_CHARACTER VALUES (10,10000),(20,20000),(30,30000),(40,40000),(50,50000),(60,60000)

GO
```

Option 1 would be to join multiple times.

```
SELECT Character1
      ,c1.SpecialPoints
      ,CASE WHEN c1.SpecialPoints > 50000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END Character1_50000PlusPoints
      ,Character2
      ,c2.SpecialPoints
      ,CASE WHEN c2.SpecialPoints > 50000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END Character2_50000PlusPoints
      ,Character3
      ,c3.SpecialPoints
      ,CASE WHEN c2.SpecialPoints > 50000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END Character3_50000PlusPoints
  FROM            USER_ACCOUNT a
        LEFT JOIN USER_CHARACTER c1 ON a.Character1 = c1.CharacterID
        LEFT JOIN USER_CHARACTER c2 ON a.Character2 = c2.CharacterID
        LEFT JOIN USER_CHARACTER c3 ON a.Character3 = c3.CharacterID

GO
```

Option 2 would be use a UNION

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT AccountID
        ,CharacterID
        ,SpecialPoints
    FROM USER_ACCOUNT a
         INNER JOIN 
         USER_CHARACTER b ON a.Character1 = b.CharacterID
    UNION ALL
  SELECT AccountID
        ,CharacterID
        ,SpecialPoints
    FROM USER_ACCOUNT a
         INNER JOIN 
         USER_CHARACTER b ON a.Character2 = b.CharacterID
    UNION ALL
  SELECT AccountID
        ,CharacterID
        ,SpecialPoints
    FROM USER_ACCOUNT a
         INNER JOIN 
         USER_CHARACTER b ON a.Character3 = b.CharacterID
)
SELECT *
  FROM cte
 WHERE SpecialPoints > 50000
```